# JQ filter by sub array - with hyphen in attribute name

Tags: jq

I have the following data file:

```json
[
  {
    "createTime": "2021-12-15T09:39:59.812377Z",
    "etag": "\"15d377a6a77bab\"",
    "labels": {
      "is-secret": "false"
    },
    "name": "projects/xxx/secrets/xxx",
    "replication": {
      "automatic": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "createTime": "2021-12-19T03:47:53.594568Z",
    "etag": "\"15d377a868c624\"",
    "labels": {
      "is-secret": "true"
    },
    "name": "projects/xxx/secrets/xxx",
    "replication": {
      "automatic": {}
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to select all elements that have a label of is-secret=true using the following query:

```
cat data.txt | jq '.[] | map(select( any(.labels[]; .is-secret == "true" )))'
```

Output needs to be an array.

Yields: jq: 1 compile error

Can anyone help?
Cheers

Comment: Is the output supposed to be an array containing these elements, or the elements separately, not in an array?

Comment: Array containing full element - so parent of label, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `map(select(...))` to the array directly and get the filtered array back:

```sh
jq 'map(select(.labels["is-secret"] == "true"))'
```

You also have to quote `is-secret` because of the hyphen; the square bracket notation is optional, but is what the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar) uses; thus

```sh
jq 'map(select(.labels."is-secret" == "true"))'
```

would also work.

Comment: This is excellent thanks, the bracket was what I was missing

Comment: Should `.labels."is-secret"` work as well ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes. Despite what the answer says, square brackets aren't actually needed. It's quoting that's needed.